# Why tkinter shows same image in different widget even images are loaded separately?

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

[image: Bottom image should be profile.jpg but it's repeated by bg.jpg which is the first one.]

First image is for background which is shows 2 times, And second one is a profile image which in not showing, Both photos are present in same root directory and have same format (jpg).

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import json

with open('config.json') as config_data:
    data = json.load(config_data)['variables']


root = Tk()
root.title(data['title'])
##TODO: for full screen
# root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'true')

# MAIN BG SECTION:
image = Image.open("bg.jpg")
image = image.resize((1620, 880), Image.ANTIALIAS)
bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

# PHOTO FRAME SECTION:
canvas = Canvas(width=data['canvas_width'], heigh=data['canvas_height'], bg="gray11")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg_image, anchor=NW)

frame_image = Image.open("profile.jpg")
frame_image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
f_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame_image)
photo_Label = Label(root, image=f_image).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `frame_image = image.resize(...)` should be `frame_image = frame_image.resize(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 what shoul i do for displaying profile inside the canvas?

Comment: Do the same as `bg_image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @acw1668 mentioned `frame_image = image.resize(...)` should be `frame_image = frame_image.resize(...)`